# Reclassify a Vector Landuse file using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, reclassify

I am trying to reclassify a landuse dataset using v.reclass in QGIS but my algoritm seems not to be working. It is a simple reclassification:
1 = 5, 2 = 0, 3 = 10, 4 = 3, 5 = 9, 6 = 4, 7 = 0
Does anyone has any experience using v.reclass or has another idea how to reclassify the data by maybe using another tool.

Comment: Which is the geometry type of your layer? A point, a line, a polygon?

Comment: It is a Polygon

Comment: Using `Field calculator` can be an option? (tedious, though...)

Comment: Actually, @Kazuhito, a `CASE WHEN` expression would be very fast to apply and I think it could be a good solution for the issue :)

Comment: I did try the field calculator but could not find a working algorithm yet but I will try again. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @mgri  and @LaTradision Thank you. I will post expression using `CASE WHEN` as an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example (please modify as necessary). "landuse" should be your actual field name of original class.

```
CASE
WHEN "landuse"  = 1 THEN 5
WHEN "landuse"  = 2 THEN 0
WHEN "landuse"  = 3 THEN 10
WHEN "landuse"  = 4 THEN 3
WHEN "landuse"  = 5 THEN 9
WHEN "landuse"  = 6 THEN 4
WHEN "landuse"  = 7 THEN 0
ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: @Kazuhito, exactly!